# toggle button visibility not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a webbrowser that uses a simple forward and backward navigation scheme, and may also refresh or stop navigation if the user so choses. All navigation is working correctly, but my issue arises when I try to toggle the 'refresh' and 'stop' buttons depending on whether the webbrowser is Navigating or has Navigated. I would like for the refresh button to be set to visible as long as no navigation is occuring, and for the stop button to be set to visible while navigation is occuring. My basic implementation is as follows but I cannot seem to get the buttons to toggle from Visible to Collapsed depending on these scenarios.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Button x:Name="RefreshButton" Content="" Style="{StaticResource RefreshBtn}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Visible" Click="RefreshButton_Click" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
<Button x:Name="StopButton" Content="" Style="{StaticResource StopBtn}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed" Click="StopButton_Click" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"/>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Change Navigation buttons if the browser is currently Navigating
        if (TheBrowser._IsNavigating == false)
        {
            RefreshButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            StopButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            RefreshButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            StopButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        //while (TheBrowser._IsNavigating == true)
        //{
        //    RefreshButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        //    StopButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        //}
    }
```

WebBrowser.xaml.cs

```
//Flag to check if the browser is navigating
    public bool _IsNavigating = false;

void TheWebBrowser_Navigating(object sender,
        Microsoft.Phone.Controls.NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        _IsNavigating = true;
    }

    void TheWebBrowser_Navigated(object sender,
        System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        _IsNavigating = false;
    }
```

My WebBrowser.xaml.cs is a webbrowser user control which is embedded into MainPage.xaml and named TheBrowser. When debugging, I can see the changes in the bool variable _IsNavigating between true and false as shown above but this change is not detected in MainPage.xaml.cs which is why I think the button visibility does not change. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.. I have run out of ideas of how to fix this! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The code for setting the visibility is in the wrong place, right now it is only called upon page construction.

You have to call the code whenever your `_isNavigating` variable changes.

Do the following:

```
 void ChangeVisibility()
 {
    if (TheBrowser._IsNavigating == false)
    {
        RefreshButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        StopButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    else
    {
        RefreshButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        StopButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
  }

void TheWebBrowser_Navigating(object sender,
    Microsoft.Phone.Controls.NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    _IsNavigating = true;
    ChangeVisibility();
}

void TheWebBrowser_Navigated(object sender,
    System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    _IsNavigating = false;
    ChangeVisibility();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the only problem is my navigating events and webbrowser control are in a seperate user control class that I am referencing from my main project in MainPage so I cannot control button visibility in MainPage.xaml.cs from WebBrowser.xaml.cs. I was attempting to check WebBrowser.xaml.cs  from MainPage.xaml.cs to see if _IsNavigating = true and then change button visibility in MainPage.xaml.cs accordingly but this does not work. Any ideas?